# Defining Functions

Tags: function-construction

I have the following matrix:

```
  M = {{En + 2 Cos[k a] t, t1 + t2 Cos [k a]},{t1 + t2 Cos [k a], En + 2 Cos[k a] t}};
```

I want the eigen value to be function of t,t1 and t2 so that they can be manipulated: So I do the following:

```
  eig=Eigenvalues[M];
  eg[t1_, t_, t2_] := eig[[1]];
```

But in the information of eg, it shows:

```
Global`eg
eg[t1_,t_,t2_]:=eig[[1]]
```

But if I print out eig and copy the expression in

```
eg[t1_,t_,t2_]:=En - t1 + 2 t Cos[a k] - t2 Cos[a k];(*The expression of eig[[1]]*)
```

I get what I want. Could someone explain me where I am going wrong and how to get it correct without the copy pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

```
eg[t1_, t_, t2_] := Evaluate[eig[[1]]]
```

or

```
eg[t1_, t_, t2_] = eig[[1]]
```

The reason for this is `eig` needs to be evaluated before the function is called with the arguments. If you use [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html), the `eig[[1]]` remains unevaluated until the function is called. Let me illustrate.

```
fun = {x + 1, y};
f[x_] := fun[[1]];
g[x_] = fun[[1]];
?f
?g
```

> `f[x_]:=fun[[1]]`
>
> `g[x_]=1+x`

```
f[2]
g[2]
```

> `1+x`
>
> `3`

Let's [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html)

```
f[2] // Trace
g[2] // Trace
```

> `{f[2],fun[[1]],{fun,{1+x,y}},{1+x,y}[[1]],1+x}`
>
> `{g[2],1+2,3}`

So, as you see, `f` ignores the argument since pattern matching of the argument to the RHS is done first in a function call, but `fun` as a symbol doesn't match to `x_`. The RHS is then evaluated, but by the time `x` appears, the pattern matching was over. In the case of `g`, the RHS contains `x`, so the argument is matched and the whole expression is evaluated with the new value. Instead of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)you can force evaluate the RHS using [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html).